# Return Row label for closest match in array calculation

Tags: arrays, excel

I have two lists of GPS coordinates in excel.  The first represents a sequential track along a trail.  The second is a list of specific waypoints that are near the track.  I am wanting to put the waypoints in order along the trail.

Using an array formula, I can find the minimum discrepancy between the track points Lat and Long for each waypoint.  However, I am stuck in trying to figure out how to return which track point that calculations belongs to.

Here is a snippet of the data on the track sheet:

[Track Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxBmC.png)

And here is the waypoint sheet along with my array calculation to find minimum difference:

[Waypoint Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEBkC.png)

As you can see, I am using the following array formula to find the lowest difference by adding the absolute values of the differences between Lat and Long for the current waypoint and all track points:

`{=MIN(ABS(A2-track!$B$2:$B$513)+ABS(B2-track!$C$2:$C$513))}`

The place I am stuck is trying to figure out how to return which point that difference belongs to.  I have tried different combinations of `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX(MATCH())` but because the value I am looking for is calculated in an array and not actually in the track sheet, I am hitting a wall.

I have looked at quite a few questions on StackExchange about using arrays to return column or row names, but all of them are dealing with tables that explicitly include the value they are looking for.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This array-formula (confirm with C+S+E) should return the number of the track-datapoint that is closest to the Waypoint in row 2. Put in cell G2 and copy down. I did not test it though..

```
=LARGE(IF(F2=(ABS(A2-track!$B$2:$B$513)+ABS(B2-track!$C$2:$C$513)),track!$A$2:$A$513,0),1)
```

Comment: I am following the logic of your formula, but unfortunately it returns `512` for all waypoints (which is the largest track pt)

Comment: Sorry. The MIN should be deleted (edited). Now it should work.

Comment: It works!
As an obvious formula upgrade, I can remove the helper column and calculate it all at once: `{=LARGE(IF(MIN(ABS(A2-track!$B$2:$B$513)+ABS(B2-track!$C$2:$C$513))=(ABS(A2-track!$B$2:$B$513)+ABS(B2-track!$C$2:$C$513)),track!$A$2:$A$513,0),1)}`

Comment: Even better! Cheers!